# How to get current TFS license type?

Tags: tfs

There are exist one computer with installed TFS. 
I open the admin console, but didn't see any license information.
So how to identify which type of license it have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the root node on the left panel
[image]

If you have a trial, you see a **License Expires** item, with the option to change the Product key (see [Locate or Change the Product Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668758(v=vs.120).aspx)).
This is for the *Server* license.

Client licenses or CAL are not so simple, they are personal and not all users requires one. See [Access Levels](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels) and [2015 licensing white paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13350) for details. It is up to the administrator to make sure that users have the proper access for their requirements and license.

Comment: I already checked it but there are present only Edition, Product Version and Install Path.

Comment: So, specify your question. TFS has only two types of licenses Trial or not. Are you looking for your _client_ license? Or the license level for your user account?

Comment: I received this computer as present. Unsuccessful, there are dont exist  any information about licenses for installed software. So I start to check it by self. At now I cant identify is the installed TFS have license or is it trial? I didn`t see any information about license or trial period.

Comment: Added more info to answer

Comment: Ok. So if I understand correct - if there are absent License Expires item - it means that some license already installed. Its good, thx!

Comment: @GiulioVian Is the TFS 2018 has the same licensing? I couldn't see the License type in my TFS Admin console!

Comment: What do you mean with "same" ? The basic rules has not changed, but details change with new versions, e.g. 2017 has its own license (see [Whitepaper](https://www.visualstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Visual-Studio-2017-Licensing-Whitepaper-March-2017.pdf).
I suggest you to post a specific question.