# How to add a license to TeamFoundation 2018?

Tags: tfs

I am attempting to get TeamFoundation Server up and running and wanted to get it licensed before letting the programmers loose on it.

However, there does not seem to be a place to enter in my license key in the software. On their site, it states that it should be done in the Team Foundation Server Administration Console and that I should be looking for the 'License Type' and 'Product ID' sections, but I do not have these on my server.

[image]

Where do I plug in the license key, if I don't have those options?

On this post, it shows how it is supposed to look like - [How to get current TFS license type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869465/how-to-get-current-tfs-license-type)

Answer (score 1):

Since TFS 2015.2, it no longer requires you to have a valid product key to be present.
Everyone can install TFS and it now depends on the user licenses. A team of up to 5 is free and thereafter you have to follow Microsofts licensing terms by buying monthly access to each member.
You can find more at this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub?view=tfs-2018&viewFallbackFrom=vsts